# How to get a list of collection names from workfront api

Tags: rest, attask, workfront-api

I'm trying to access the collections on an object from Workfront via: `/attask/api/v4.0/approval/search?fields=approverStatuses:*`

My question is, how do I get a list of the collection names on that object if for example, the object has multiple collections, such as the object `approval`. Is there a way to use REST to get that list? This is a conflict since the collection name is not the same as the object name, example:

Object Name: approverStatus

Collection Name (under approval): approverStatuses

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this one out myself. The correct REST request is the following:

`/attask/api/v4.0/approval/metadata?fields=collectioins`

You have to access the top level object of approverStatus and it'll return a list of all the collections it has (this includes approverStatuses).